Using the GitHub Repository as a Gradle Dependency in Android project
I have forked a project from github, modified it and now I want to use my modified version as  dependency in my project. Like this:
implementation("com.github.my_user_name:library_name:master-SNAPSHOT")

For this I looked fro my repo on JitPack to see if it builds alright, and it did
but when I run the project I get this error:
Configuration cache state could not be cached: field __librarySourceSets__ of task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths of type com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MapSourceSetPathsTask`: error writing value of type 'org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath.

//build.gradle,kts(MyAppName)
@Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION") // TODO: Remove once KTIJ-19369 is fixed
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.hiltAndroid) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.plugin.serialization) apply false // needs to be as the project's JVM version
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm) apply false
}
true // Needed to make the Suppress annotation work for the plugins block

//settings.gradle.kts(MyAppName)
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://www.jitpack.io" )
        }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "MyAppNAme"
include(":app")
include(":feature:profile") // this is where I want to use the library



//build.gradle.kts(:feature:profile)
@Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION") // TODO: Remove once KTIJ-19369 is fixed
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid)
    alias(libs.plugins.hiltAndroid)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.plugin.serialization)
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.feature.profile"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
            // excludes += "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
            // Avoid SRT and RTMP clash, from StreamPack
            pickFirsts += "**/*.so"
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        //kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.4" // !important to keep this version
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.github.my_user_name:library_name:master-SNAPSHOT")
}

Is this the right way to use github repo as a dependency. If not, what am I doing wrong?

Just forking the repo isn't enough to have it recognized/found/pulled in by the plugin management system - you need to publish it... likely to Maven.
I'd first recommend publishing locally to validate things - this will load your local Maven install as a 'source' and you can test the library.
When you're ready / if you need to, you can publish to Maven Central.
Here's a decent reference
Publish Java artifact to Maven Local with Gradle

I could use it as a git-submodule as well and not have to publish it on Maven or Jitpack.

You definitely could do that.
